# Has anyone written a thread-safe BindingList<T>?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, bindinglist

I am currently getting exceptions when modifying an IBindingList on multiple threads. Does anyone have a threadsafe version before I write my own?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll find this an incredibly difficult task. The easier path would be to prevent multiple-thread access with a `lock`:

```
void AddItemToList(object o)
{
    lock(myBindingList)
    {
        myBindingList.Add(o);
    }
}
```

Look at the [lock statement docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't that be lock (_mySyncObject)?

Comment: That's insufficient. Data binding won't respect your lock. When the binding list changes, the UI will immediately attempt to update and you'll get a cross thread error.

Answer (score 1):

Only just found this post... do you mean [like this](http://groups.google.co.uk/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.csharp/msg/f12a3c5980567f06)?

Comment: Bit of a shallow implementation. What about all the other zillions of methods that would need to be syncrononized (not least of which: GetEnumerator())?